# How does the SSO feature return back to the application? (iPhone)

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, single-sign-on

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Facebook SSO know which app to return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953229/how-does-facebook-sso-know-which-app-to-return-to)

I am currently working on a project involving logging into facebook using the SSO. When I perform a SSO login (having been already logged in on the facebook app), what appears to be a facebook window briefly opens and closes, taking me back to the app after performing the SSO. 
I was wondering, **what function in the Facebook developers library is responsible for returning me to the application I was running?**

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook app simply calls a URL when it's done. The same URL you set up as a URL scheme for your app.
 You can set your own URL scheme for your app then whenever that URL is used (eg. A link on a webpage) it'll open your app.